# ANR on simpledateformat

Tags: android, simpledateformat, android-anr-dialog

I am using SimpleDateFormat in my android project. On one device an ANR occurred (in firebase console shown) . I could not understand why ANR occurred.

```
fun String.toDate(format: String = CALENDAR_DATE_FORMAT): Date? {
    return runCatching {
        SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.getDefault()).parse(this)
    }.getOrNull()
}
```

log :

```
main (runnable): tid=1 systid=21556 
       at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.compile(SimpleDateFormat.java:826)
       at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.initialize(SimpleDateFormat.java:720)
       at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.<init>(SimpleDateFormat.java:691)
       at com.skylb.mooncalendar.app.util.ExtensionsKt.toDate(Extensions.kt:67)
       at com.skylb.mooncalendar.app.util.ExtensionsKt.toDate$default(Extensions.kt:65)
```

Comment: Consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends. Use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) in order to use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem systematically on that device where it occurs?